# tab bar item position not lined up with the background of the bar

Tags: objective-c

Im having trouble trying to implement my own design to a tab bar. Somehow the items and background don't align correctly even tho they have the same height. The buttons seem to be further up than the background and i can't figure out why.

Code for implementing the items/buttons:
(this is added in my "viewDidLoad" in "Tab1ViewController.m", wich is the first of my 5 view controllers)

```
UIImage *selectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"searchSEL"];
UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search"];

UIImage *selectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"homeSEL"];
UIImage *unselectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home"];

UIImage *selectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dareSEL"];
UIImage *unselectedImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dare"];

UIImage *selectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"starSEL"];
UIImage *unselectedImage3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star"];

UIImage *selectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"friendsSEL"];
UIImage *unselectedImage4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"friends"];

UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *item3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
UITabBarItem *item4 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

[item0 setTitle:@""];
[item1 setTitle:@""];
[item2 setTitle:@""];
[item3 setTitle:@""];
[item4 setTitle:@""];
[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage1];
[item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage2 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage2];
[item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage3 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage3];
[item4 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage4 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage4];
```

and to add the background i just added this code to my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in my appDelegate.m

```
UITabBar *tabBar = [UITabBar appearance];
[tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"]];
```

The buttons are 64x49px and the background is 320x49px.

I wont be able to answer to or read comments in a while, but I will as soon as i can, hopefully someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, figured it out and it was kind of obvious. The part under the items are where the title should be. And since my icons just took up the icon space and not the title space, there was a emptiness under where the title would be.

Solved the problem by creating a whole background image for the bar and specified borders and gradient on that instead and just created the icons separately ass small white/black images and transparent background.